# Can anyone add a censorship tag?

Tags: discussion

I'd have wanted to add it to this question:

[Why doesn't iTunes allow to search for podcasts related to Uyghurs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357500/why-doesnt-itunes-allow-to-search-for-podcasts-related-to-uyghurs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags should be used to describe what the question is about, not what a potential answer is. So in your case the question is about how (podcast) search works within iTunes, it should be tagged accordingly.